# Wordpress Houzez theme's front end login form nothing happens?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, caching, cookies

My site is [property168.com](https://property168.com/)

The front end login form in navigation link nothing happens after click login.
It's back normal again after I clear cache and preload cache with wp-rocket immediately.

I think it back to "nothing happens" again after 24 hours since wp-rocket clear cache it self.

Any ideas?

Comment: please read this: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/313-user-cache

Comment: @GrafiCode Thanks for the link. I'm trying to make changes as the link above suggests and I'am waiting for WP Rocket to do a clear cache it self. And We'll see if it works or not.